# Fried ground wire

Tags: wiring

What caused the ground wire in my ceiling fan to fry?
When I turned on the fan it "popped" and a spark flew out. When I disconnected the fan the ground wire was blackened.

Comment: Not enough info to give an accurate answer. 
How was everything connected? Any other symptoms? Was everything working at the time?

Answer (score 1):

That is a ground wire doing its intended job which is to provide a direct short under insulation failure so the breaker works to cut the power and keep any metal in contact with the fault at ground potential to prevent shock hazard.

Is the blackened part you refer to the **fan's ground pigtail** or the wiring the fan hooks up to? Shorts cause intense heat that can cause the bare copper to turn color.

Using an ohmmeter, look for motor windings shorted to ground, wires that were run over sharp edges or trapped between assembly pieces that have had their insulation cut. You will probably find a nice burn mark and melting where the pop and spark came from.

In the newer electronic speed / remote switch type, also look for a cheap, improperly designed controller that was not "fail safe" and has developed a similar short to ground. It will smell of electronic death.

Comment: It was the green ground wire that was burned, the breaker did not trip. The black and white wires look undamaged.

Comment: Umm... Don't like the sounds of that. Would help to post a picture so we know what exactly is burnt. NM/UF type cable typically has a bare copper ground wire, not a green insulated wire. This is US power, correct?

Comment: @FiascoLabs The green insulated wire is probably the ground wire provided with the fan.  There's usually green wires in the fan wiring, and from the fan mounting bracket.

Comment: @Tester101 - Yep, I'm pretty sure it was a less than adequate ground pigtail coming off the fan. Small size, extra heat = burnt insulation.

Comment: but if current went to ground and the GFCI didn't trip then there is a problem in the wiring in the house

Comment: @ratchetfreak - GFCI on a ceiling fan? Doubt it. A bad circuit breaker, maybe.

Comment: @FiascoLabs I meant the GFCI for the whole house, in my jurisdiction those are mandatory

Comment: @ratchetfreak - For better understanding, where is that located?

Comment: @FiascoLabs main panel; the second breaker after the power enters the house. aka it trips and you have no power in the house

Comment: @ratchetfreak - I needed to be more specific (grin), what country? I've heard whole house GFCI is required in various European countries, primarily as an arc-fault protection due to the higher voltages typically used.

Comment: @FiascoLabs oh, Belgium